# How do I suppress my guns?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

1. As a Counter-Terrorist, the game didn't automatically suppress my M4A1 after I bought it. How do I attach the suppressor?
2. What other guns can be suppressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The game didn't automatically suppress my M4A1 after I bought it

The weapons that have a silencer available should have it by default. Maybe you are confusing the [M4A4](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/M4A4) with the [M4A1](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/M4A1-S)?

> How do I attach the suppressor?

By equipping the weapon and using the alternate fire button (the default is Right Click).

> What other guns can be suppressed?

The [M4A1-S](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/M4A1-S), [USP-S](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/USP-S) and [MP5-SD](https://counterstrike.fandom.com/wiki/MP5-SD) (for the later is not detachable).